# given a pcap file, how to find if a src ip address is local or remote using jpcap

Tags: java, pcap, jpcap

Given a pcap file, how can I find out which src ip addresses are local and which are remote using jpcap?
Can any one guide me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't.

There's nothing intrinsic in a pcap entry to tell you whether the packet was inbound or outbound.

You'll need a configuration file to tell you which IPs are considered "local".

Answer (score 1):

To determine whether an address is local to the machine on which your pcap-based application is running, the `pcap_findalldevs()` routine can be used to get a list of all interfaces on that machine, complete with lists of IPv4 and IPv6 addresses assigned to each of the interfaces.  I don't know whether jpcap includes support for `pcap_findalldevs()`.